# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const S8*'

Tags: c++

I have a S8 type define, and a debug print function using that defined type.

```
typedef signed char S8;
S32 CH_COM_DebugPrintf(const S8 *rpc_format, ...)
```

when I invoke this printf function like below,

```
CH_COM_DebugPrintf("TunerCallback device id:[%d]\r\n", ri_Device);
CH_COM_DebugPrintf("TunerCallback event type:[%d]\r\n", renm_EventType);
```

when compiling, it give out error, what's wrong?

```
arm-hisiv200-linux-g++ -I./gtest/include -I../drv/include -g -Wall -Wextra -c src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc: In function 'void CHDRV_TEST_TunerCallback(S32, CHDRV_TUNER_EVENT_TYPE_e, void*)':
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const S8*'
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc:30: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'S32 CH_COM_DebugPrintf(const S8*, ...)'
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc:31: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const S8*'
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc:31: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'S32 CH_COM_DebugPrintf(const S8*, ...)'
src/chdrv_tunner_test.cc: At global scope:
```

it didn't work as I force to convert to (const S8*), please give me some help regard this. very appreciated your help.

```
CH_COM_DebugPrintf((S8*)"TunerCallback device id:[%d]\r\n", ri_Device);
CH_COM_DebugPrintf((S8*)"TunerCallback event type:[%d]\r\n", renm_EventType);
```

Comment: Your `S8` is `signed char` and, IIRC, the 3 types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are distinct (with `char` having the same representation as one of the other two, but still being a different type for the compiler). So there is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `signed char*`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/basic.html) (3.9.1  Fundamental types):

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types.

A string literal in the form of `"text"` consists of `const char` and not a `const signed char` or `const unsigned char`.

Since they are pointer types you can easily cast them to each other, but that won't be done implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

The type of a string literal is `char []`, an array of `char`.  When passed to a function like this, it will be evaluated as a pointer to its first element, a `char *`.

`char` and `signed char` are distinct types (even if `char` is signed on your platform).  A pointer to one cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to the other.

Your function should be declared with the first parameter as `const char *` if you want to pass string literals without an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
CH_COM_DebugPrintf((S8*)"TunerCallback device id:[%du]\r\n", ri_Device);
CH_COM_DebugPrintf((S8*)"TunerCallback event type:[%du]\r\n", renm_EventType);
```

printing as unsigned values

Maybe you should use `typedef unsigned char S8;` instead of `signed` values, because device id and callback types representations  are semantically positive values.

Comment: `%du` is not the correct way to print unsigned values. In any case, this has nothing to do with the actual issue, and you don't actually know that these variables are unsigned because their types weren't shown in the question.

Comment: I guess `u` was a typo, not anything related to `unsigned`

Comment: @anatolyg The answer specifically mentions unsigned values. It just makes no sense, and why someone chose to upvote it is beyond me.